# TextMate scope for triple quoted Python docstrings

Tags: syntax-highlighting, textmate, visual-studio-code, docstring

I'm currently setting up VS Code for Python development. I'd like to have triple-quoted docstrings highlighted as comments, not as strings, i.e. grey instead of light green in this picture:

[image]

I know that I can adjust this in the TextMate rules for this theme, but I can't figure out the right scope for Python docstrings. I thought I would be something like this:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Predawn]": {
        "comments": "#777777",
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "string.quoted.triple",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#777777"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

but that does not have the desired effect, even after restarting the editor. Does anyone know what the right scope is?

Comment: From command palette `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes`

Comment: @Alex What am I supposed to make of this?

Comment: `string.quoted.docstring.multi` ?

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed show the scope of the currently highlighted code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this one

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
      {           
          "scope": [
              "string.quoted.multi.python",
              "string.quoted.double.block.python",
              "string.quoted.triple",
              "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python",
              "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python punctuation.definition.string.begin.python",
              "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python punctuation.definition.string.end.python",
              "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python constant.character.escape.python"
          ],          
          "settings": {
              "foreground": "#777777" //change to your preference
          }       
      }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on the comments above, the scopes are:

**For docstrings:** `string.quoted.docstring.multi.python` for `""" '''` (or `.single` for `' "`)

**For triple quote strings that are not docstrings:** `string.quoted.multi.python`

The scope `string.quoted.triple` is not used, even though it appears in settings.json autocomplete.